# Python: Warning and after Error using SCons

Tags: python, scons

I am trying to install the openWSN platform on my MAC OS X, to be able to run tests in a simulated (or real) sensors network. For that, is necessary the Python development headers and libraries. In fact, I think the headers are already installed, as I have already downloaded XCode, Command Line Tools, Homebrew, and I already downloaded the Python.

I am using SCons to construct the software application.
The big problem is that when I type this command on the terminal:

```
$ scons board=python toolchain=gcc oos_openwsn
```

The processing seems to be going well, when I receive the following warning and error:

```
File "/Users/stage/Desktop/openwsn/openwsn-fw/SConscript", line 578, in sconscript_scanner
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
Linking (shared)   firmware/openos/projects/common/oos_openwsn.so

**ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/libs'**

ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic-functions
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
scons: *** [firmware/openos/projects/common/oos_openwsn.so] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The problem to me seems to be in the libs folder, as if the scons could not find this folder, and cannot proceed.

Comment: Is really hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the build scripts. Have you verified that that lib dir exists? And i don't recognize the -B option, are you sure its correct?

Answer (score 2):

I checked the SCons files for the project https://github.com/openwsn-berkeley/openwsn-fw that you seem to be using. I don't see any hints that the compilation and installation of sources is supported for MacOS. Are you sure that the project supports your OS? If you are, you should consider asking the project's maintainers for help, e.g. via ML or IRC.

The main error in your output above is the "`ld: unknown option: -Bsymbolic-functions`". Since you specified "`toolchain=gcc`" in your call, this is what the build expects...but you don't seem to have a proper `gcc` installed. The `clang` compiler that is found instead doesn't know the provided command-line option, and stops with an error.